# C Structures Bus Error 10

Tags: c, struct, structure

I have a stuct in C, and I use a function to get the values for the structure from the user. Below is my structure.

```
typedef struct {
    char    *name;
    char    *chemical_symbol;
    char    *class;
    int     atomic_number;
    double  atomic_weight;
    int     *electrons;
} element_t;
```

This is the function I am using to get the values from the user. The problem lies in this function after asking for the chemical symbol. I get Bus Error: 10. My understanding of a bus error is when the processor cant attempt the memory access. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
element_t scan_element() {

    element_t element;

    printf ("Enter New Element Information:\n\n");

    printf("Element Name: ");
    scanf("%s", element.name);

    printf("Element Chemical Symbol: ");
    scanf("%s", element.chemical_symbol);

    printf("Element Class: ");
    scanf("%s", element.class);

    printf("Element Atomic Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &element.atomic_number);

    printf("Element Atomic Weight: ");
    scanf("%lf", &element.atmoic_weight);

    printf("Element Electrons: ");
    scanf("%p", &element.electrons);

    return(element);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("Element Name: ");
scanf("%s", element.name);
```

You have to allocate memory for the object pointed by `element.name` for example by using `malloc`. Without proper allocation `element.name` is an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't allocate enough memory to attempt to read into your strings.

BTW, your last `scanf` is strange: do you really want to ask an address? It could be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory.  Perhaps the best (certainly *easiest*!) way is simply define your struct to have character arrays (instead of character pointers).

EXAMPLE:

```
#define MAX_STRING 80
#define MAX_ELECTRONS 32

typedef struct {
    char    name[MAX_STRING];
    char    chemical_symbol[MAX_STRING];
    char    class[MAX_STRING];
    int     atomic_number;
    double  atmoic_weight;
    int     electrons[MAX_ELECTRONS];
} element_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you scan the strings, you should allocate some space for them. For example:

```
void initialize( element_t * p ) {
  p->name = malloc( sizeof( char ) * MAXSIZE );
  p->chemical_symbol = malloc( sizeof( char ) * MAXSIZE );
  p->class = malloc( sizeof( char ) * MAXSIZE );
}
```

Before you call `scan_element`, call `initialize`. I' m sure it will compile properly.

Comment: Don't forget to `free()` strings after you are done with using them.